# Apache lounge blocking authentication header from frontend

Tags: apache

I have a project and it's on the way to BETA production.

As a Frontend, I use React and for Backend I have considered Python Django.

I am gonna host It in my own computer and I use Apache lounge for Windows OS.

I have launched my beta production and I have got some problems, when frontend sends data, Apache lounge blocks header, which contains authentication token.

The question is:

How to allow headers requests in apache lounge? At least Authentication token header

Where should I put `RequestHeader unset Authorization` in `httpd.conf`?

[Request screenshot](https://ibb.co/mTwY2dN)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Just add `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` inside of httpd.conf

Comment: ..........................